# how @ tag behaves in .properties file?? Example: dummy.PRODUCT_NAME=@DUMMY_NAME@

Tags: java, c++, gwt, web, properties

How does `@` tag behave in a `.properties` file?

Below is a snippet from my code.

```
dummy.PRODUCT_NAME=@DUMMY_NAME@
```

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that during your build (maven / ant etc) these @ values are being replaced. Take a look inside the built artifact (jar / war etc) and you will probably find that @DUMMY_NAME@ has been replaced with a 'real' value in the property file packed inside the artifact.

Comment: i tried of searching of all files. unfortunately, i dint get any clue in ant / maven files linked to DUMMY_Name...

Comment: Possibly a system property passed in at command line? It's hard to know without more info on your build. Do your artifacts get deployed to nexus? Try downloading a released version (ie non-snapshot) of the artifact from nexus and unzip it and have a look at the value in the property file for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Something else is interpreting it somewhere, either in a build or at runtime.